# Any online English dictionaries listing the previous pronunciation of words?

Tags: discussion, online-resources, pronunciation

I am interested to know the pronunciation of words in the past fifty years or so. Does anyone know any online dictionaries which list the former pronunciation of words in English language?

Comment: Your best hope is the OED (Oxford English Dictionary) but that is only available to subscribers.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thanks for commenting. The fact is I am sometimes surprised to find out that I am pronouncing a word wrongly, even though I have been confident in the correctness of that word's pronunciation. I do agree that I may have learned the wrong pronunciation in the first place, but sometimes I am sure I have heard the pronunciation of a word differently in the past. I know it may sound ridiculous, but it makes me feel disappointed because I have been putting so much time learning the correct pronunciation of English words in general.

Comment: It is possible that you hear a word being pronunciation in a different dialect, I think this is more noticeable if you are living in the States because there is such a wide variety of ethnicities, immigrants and native speakers from different states that it is possible to hear the same word pronounced in many different ways, but no online dictionary could possibly contain all the possible variations. The best dictionaries list the most common pronunciations. Try [Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/) instead

Comment: This could help: http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/changing-voices/phonological-change/